# List item strike-through react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a todolist in React, I can delete todo-s but I want to apply strike-through for completed todos. After that it would be great to list them as completed. How is it possible? What should I change in my code? I tried to use objects in the array, but that lead to diff, erros.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class ToDoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      items: ''
      };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);

  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({items: event.target.value})
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({
      list: [...this.state.list, this.state.items],
      items: ''
    })
    event.preventDefault();
  }


  handleRemove(index) {
    const filteredArray = this.state.list.filter((_, i) => i !== index); // used underscore as a convention to address nothing is going there
    this.setState({
      list: filteredArray
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className='header main'>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
        <label>
          <input className='new-todo'
            placeholder='What needs to be done?'
            type="text"
            value={this.state.items}
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
      </form>
      <ul className='todo-list'>
        {this.state.list.map((item, index) => (
            <li className='list-view' key={index+1}>{item}<button className='list-view-button' onClick={this.handleRemove.bind(this, index) }>X</button></li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div className='footer'>
        Remaining: {this.state.list.length}
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ToDoList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well currently you only have an array of strings that represents the todos.

I would do this for your items state:

`items: [
    {
        desc: "todo content",
        status: "new"
    },
    {
        desc: "todo content",
        status: "completed"
    },
    {
        desc: "todo content",
        status: "archived"
    }
];`

now when you loop through the todos you can check for the status for different design display.

Or you can filter the todos, for specific status,
ie:

`this.state.items.filter(item => item.status==="new")`

this will give you only the "new" todos.